# how to i calculate the total sum

Tags: php, mysql

As the title stated;

1. How do i calculate `TOTAL` when user checked multiple checkboxs on the selected hotel?

and

2. How do i make it so that whenever a `TOTAL` is added and the current `TOTAL` (which is in mysql) exceed 500k, an alert will pop saying `BUDGET EXCEEDED`

Thanks you!

CODE:

```
  <?php

require ("config.php");
$link = mysqli_connect($h,$u,$p,$db)
   OR die(mysqli_error());

   $query = "select  BIL, HOTEL, TOTAL, address from HOTELS"
   OR DIE(mysqli_error());
   $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

   echo "<table border=2>";
   echo "<tr><th><b>HOTEL</th><th><b>TOTAL(RM)</th><th>ADDRESS</th></tr>";

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   { 

       echo "<tr><td>$row[HOTEL]</td>";
       echo "<td>RM $row[TOTAL]</td>";
       echo "<td>$row[address]</td>";
       echo "<td><a href='delete.php?del=$row[BIL] '>Delete</a></td>";
       echo "<td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value='{$row['HOTEL']}'></td></tr>" ;
   }

?>
```

Comment: You either have to do this in Javascript on the client, or put everything in a form that gets submitted to the server. The script that processes the form can calculate the total.

Comment: @Barmar at first i wanted to do that, but the total hotel is ALOT, its troublesome if i have to do it in form plus someone already input everything in database, so i thought i just called it back and calculate using form, is it possible? and if js how do i do it?

Comment: Your code is running before the user checks any of the checkboxes. You can't calculate the total until after you send it to the user and they start checking thngs.

Comment: @Barmar can you point of where that needed to be corrected cause i rather new in this field, thank you!

Comment: The sum of something is like 5 + 5 = 10, where 10 would be the sum of 5+5. Hope this helps! XD

Answer (score -1):

Use JavaScript or JQuery (JS library).

Whenever a checkbox selected/deselected, retrieve the value from corresponding 'total' cell

`$selected_val = $(this).parent.(".total").text //sample in jquery,`

and remove the 'RM' word. then +/- the value in total.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, sorry but where should i put the code? i rather new in this field. Thank you

Comment: @SyedShahrulShafiq You need to learn Javascript. We can't teach you this here.

Comment: Please go to www.w3schools.com or tutorial point to start learning js. easy enough to learn and understand.